# Passing URL entered by user to 404 page with Htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I have a website with PHP and htaccess support.
Basically, I want to pass the URL entered by the user (that caused the 404) to the 404 page itself.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following rule in your `.htaccess` file.

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

In the `error.php` file.

```
<?php // error.php
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]. " doesn't exists. Sorry!";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following in your .htaccess file (where 404.php is your error page)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding the following rule in .htaccess.

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

In your 404.php you can write

```
<h3>
Page Not Found.
</h3>
<div>
     <p>Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found.</p>
     <ul>
        <li>You may have mistyped the page address.</li>
        <li>You may have clicked on a link that has not been updated.</li>
        <li>We have recently changed our site structure and the page has been moved to new location.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can style this to display it properly.

Hope this helps :)